# How to set an appropriate thread number for my thread pool on the server side?

Tags: java, multithreading

I just want to ask a rookie question: How to set an appropriate thread number for my thread pool on the server side?

1. Are there any general rules or formulas I can follow?
2. What are the issues I have to consider? For example, the number of network requests per second, the number of CPU cores, the CPU and memory usage rate in my application, the hardware I use on my server, etc.

Comment: It largely depends on what your program _does_ to start with...

Comment: @fge a web server which processes web requests.

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically the size of the pool should be set to the the maximum possible of commands executed concurrently on your configuration, like if you have 4 cores (without HyperThreading), then you can set it to 4. With hyperthreading, you can set it to 8.

There are however questions like: what is the expected behaviour of the application, if it wants to get a thread from the pool, but the pool is empty (like you had 8 threads in the pool, every single one if them is working on a video encoding job in the next 10 minutes, and you get a new request in your manager thread).

You should consider however, that it is NOT guaranteed, that all your threads will run in every moment, even if your application handles threading exceptionally perfectly, as other applications are running on your computer meanwhile (your OS for example), and they need CPU as well.

On the other hand it is also a big question, that what does a thread do in your pool? You provided no informations about what is this thread pool used for, are they used in your own app, or you want to configure an open-source app/commercial app, etc. Creating and managing threads do have serious costs (scheduling, context switching, etc.), which may worth only if, the your threads stay alive long enough (you can provide enough job them to work on).

For further details, a quite good starting point in this subject could be Google I guess, for the following keywords: "scheduling, concurrency, threads, java executor service, hyperthreading".

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide enough information about my application. My application is a web server and the thread pool is used to respond to web requests. Let's talk it more specificly. If I want to develop a web server which processes 2000 requests per second, what is the appropriate number of threads in the pool? Can I figure it out theoretically, or do I have to get the number by experiments?

Comment: Well, it still depends on the characteristics of your application running in the container (avg response time per request), and your system's concurrency level (concurrent threads). Here are some articles however on server sizing: [**Tuning the Size of your Thread Pool**](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-Thread-Pool-Performance-Tuning), [Tomcat configuration](http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.hu/2009/01/tomcat-maxthreads-configuration.html). The first one is very correct, in your case I think this is what you need! :)